# How use ES6, commonJS in rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I don't understand how use [`html5sortable`](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable) with `rails` 6 + webpacker. `html5sortable` available as ES6 Module, AMD, CommonJS and iffe. I can't connect it( Please help me

I exeсuted:

```
yarn add html5sortable
```

Add line to `app/javascript/admin.js`:

```
require('html5sortable')
```

But i get:

```
sortable is not defined
```

My [git](https://github.com/Cheshir74/MCS) repository

Comment: Did you install the package? It is not in your package.json

Comment: Yea, i install. sorry, this in last commit https://github.com/Cheshir74/MCS/commit/24ee1a4fa949250f725c4641ce133628991ae063 I try use 'import html5sortable', but this don't work too(

Comment: Try `const sortable = require("dist/html5sortable.cjs.js")` as mentioned in the [installation](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable#installation) or alternatively `import sortable from "dist/html5sortable.es.js"`.

Comment: Thank you. I use import sortable from "html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.cjs" in other file, where i call sortable function (galleries.js)